# How to locate the element using selenium python in the HTML below

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to do some automatic test using selenium .But i met some wired thing that I can't locate the element. So could anyone tell me how to deal with this.
I've tried something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@onclick="addRule"]').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.addbutton')
```

Nothing works..

[image]

Comment: This element is inside iframe, you need to switch to iframe first to locate this element.

Comment: Yes @kapil u r right

Comment: thank you bro,it works.  @Kapil

Comment: Good @kapil You are sharp to see iframe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

I saw there is a frame too

so first switch to frame:

```
  driver.switch_to_frame("contents")

  driver.find_element_by_class_name('addbutton"]').click()
```